# Hide Pie Chart Slice on Load

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I would like to hide a pie chart slice on load but cannot figure out how to do so.
I'm not sure it's possible, but it seems like it might be. There is a property "selected", but it does not seem to change when I manually select or unselect a wedge via the legend. I've tried to dispatchAction like this example ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/woqlnzyznl?file=/src/components/Candlestick.vue)), but haven't had any luck:

Comment: You can remove/add it in your series anytime you want to hide/show it, then refresh the chart.

Comment: I’d like it to show up clickable in the legend, not just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close to the solution... Actually, you should tweak [`legend.selected`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend.selected).

Take a look at this basic example:

```js
let option = {
  legend: {
    selected: {
      'B': false // <--- HERE
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      data: [
        { value: 10, name: 'A' },
        { value: 20, name: 'B' },
        { value: 15, name: 'C' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```